# vue lazy transpilation using webpack

Tags: webpack

is there a way by which we can transpile a webpage with webpack on runtime and return to the user.

the index.html page can have a webpack.***.js file

but the pages it is accessing needs to treanspiled runtime from a node.js server.

Is there a possibility for the same.